# Trimmed body field only show first paragraph

Tags: views, entities

(update: it not a problem relate to uppercases)
I think I found a bug but not sure which module is causing it. Maybe CCK...

I have a content type with the body field set (through manage display) to be shown as **Trimmed** to lenght: 400

Then I created a node with 2 paragraphs of text in the body . When I load the full view of the node the trimming only shows the first paragraph

the trimming works fine if I enter this text in the body:

```
some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
```

the trimming also works fine if I enter this text in the body **(notide that the second paragraph is a short paragraph)**

```
both paragraph are shown
some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
```

but only the first paragraph is shown if I enter this text in the body **(notice that the second paragraph is longer)**

```
only this paragraph is shown 
some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some textsome text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some textsome text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some textsome text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some textsome text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: no one? some help please.

Comment: what version of Drupal and views are you using?  Is there anything else special about your setup?  I can't replicate the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is a custom formatter. Create a custom formatter with the [custom formatters module](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters):

> The Custom Formatters module allows users to easily create custom
>   CCK/Field Formatters without the need to write a custom module. Custom
>   Formatters can then be exported as CTools Exportables/Features or
>   Drupal API Formatters.

Once installed just write some php code and format and insert the particular text that you're looking for.

Comment: good idea, but using php to trim text with html tags could generate a trimmed text with unclosed tags. What do you think?

Comment: Just strip all html tags with php's `strip_tag`. After that's done wrap the text with the <p> tag again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Custom Formatters module but if you're not doing anything special with the formatting and just want a plain text output with a character limit, you should be able to do this with just Views settings without any additional modules.

Comment: @nmc I set the view to be styled as **Content | Teaser**. What you say would be useful if I had styled the views as **Field**, then I would have set the output for the body field.